# Simple way to map complex JSON in JAX-RS?

Tags: json, jax-rs

I need to get the JSON structure:

```
{
  "check_time": 1439817437,
  "checks": {
    "memory": {
      "text": "memory usage OK",
      "status": "OK",
      "memory_used": {
        "current_value": "908644912",
        "type": "gauge",
        "uom": "bytes",
        "crit": "1958923469",
        "warn": "1649619763",
        "status": "OK"
      }
    }
  },
  "summery": "my summery",
  "version": {
    "text": "$Revision: 13017 $",
    "svn_path": "$URL: foo $"
  }
}
```

To gerate this in JAX-RS you need a lot of classes.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MonitorRSModel {

    private String summery;
    private Long check_time;
    private MonitorRSVersion version;
    private MonitorRSChecks checks;

    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MonitorRSVersion {

    private String text;
    private String svn_path;

    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MonitorRSChecks {

    private MonitorRSMemory memory;

    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MonitorRSMemory {
    private String text;
    private String status;

    private MonitorRSMemoryUsed memory_used;

    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MonitorRSMemoryUsed {

    private String current_value;
    private String type = "gauge";
    private String uom = "bytes";
    private String crit;
    private String warn;
    private String status;

    ...
}
```

My structure is only a little bit complex. If the complexity grow you get a bag of classes. How can I reduce my work to generate this in JAX-RS?

Comment: are you able to get through this?

Answer (score 1):

I read about it and you may want to try : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

The jsonschema2pojo is a tool that takes a json document and generates .java source files and can reduce your work.

Note: I haven't used it so cant say how good this works for various kind of json formats.